# Move a std::map vs move all the elements of a std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, move, stdmap, std

```
std::map<int, Obj> mp;
// insert elements into mp

// case 1
std::map<int, Obj> mp2;
mp2 = std::move(mp);

// case 2
std::map<int, Obj> mp3;
std::move(std::begin(mp), std::end(mp), std::inserter(mp3, std::end(mp3));
```

I am confused by the two cases. Are they exactly the same?

Comment: The first one has a constant time complexity, the second one has *n*log*n* time complexity.

Comment: no they are not the same. Note that destination map in second case can be a bit different (for example have different order). Case 1 is super fast, case 2have to allocate some internal structure of map for `mp3`.

Comment: Note that first copy just moves the entire tree from first map to second one, first one (usually) remaining empty, while second variant due to the nature of `std::move` leaves the nodes in second tree as are, just their contents being moved: Assume `std::map<std::vector<...>>`, then the vector's contents are moved, while the vectors in the first map themselves remain (usually empty).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

- Case 1 moves the content of the whole `map` at once. The `map`'s internal pointer(s) are "moved" to `mp2` - none of the `pair`s in the map are affected.
- Case 2 moves the individual `pair`'s in the map, one by one. Note that `map` *Key* s are `const` so they can't be moved but will instead be copied. `mp` will still contain as many elements as before - but with values in an indeterminable state.

Answer (score 5):

> Are they exactly the same?

**No**, They are not!

The first one invokes the **move constructor** of the [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map)<sup>4</sup> and the move operation will be done at class/ data structure level.

> [...]
>
> 4. Move constructor.
>    After container move construction (`overload (4)`), references, pointers, and iterators (other than the end iterator) to other remain valid, but refer to elements that are now in `*this`. The current standard makes this guarantee via the blanket statement in [container.requirements.general](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#12), and a more direct guarantee is under consideration via [LWG 2321](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2321)

> **Complexity**
>
> **4**) **Constant.** If alloc is given and `alloc != other.get_allocator()`, then linear.

---

The second `std::move` is from [`<algorithm>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move), which does element wise(i.e. key value pairs) movement to the other map.

> 1. **Moves the elements in the range `[first, last)`, to another range beginning at `d_first`**, starting from first and proceeding to last - 1. After this operation the elements in the moved-from range will still contain valid values of the appropriate type, but not necessarily the same values as before the move.

> **Complexity**
>
> **Exactly `last - first`** move assignments.